# how to check what is on the map in the area of localization

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geolocation

I'm a beginner in flutter, but I want to have an application which check user geolocation at open
and check where user is, what is in the area.

eg. Let's say I have application for collecting flags.
User open my app and want to collect flag, which is mark that he is present on some location, let say the bridge on the river.

This feature has to prevent of cheating during the game.

The tricky part, for me, is to thetect what is in the area, because I can't have list of possible objects to collect. By object I mean places to visit. And I want to be sure  what to get as a place from google map to mark what is visited.

I will be great full for responces :D

[image]

I have try to get location [image]

And I have it lat and long
now, I want to know what is on the map around
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! First of all, please do read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to improve the chances of you getting help. With that said, please also avoid posting images of your code.